# Mamp and WordPress url change

Tags: php, apache, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a WordPress installation on my localhost: http://localhost:8888

I've uploaded the wp files on my FTP, and I've imported the DB. I can't use a new installation because I've edited some core files.

I also edited the table `wp_options` on my site, and edited the fields, `siteurl` and `home` so those two fields contained the site URL, changing them from "localhost:8888" to my new URL.

The problem now is when I go to my URL and try to load the website it will redirect me to http://THE_NEW_WEBSITE:8888.

I need that port removed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved before explorting the database change the url from the wordpress admin page and after that export the DB

Answer (score 3):

you don't need that port *removed*, you just haven't changed the base url of the wordpress install everywhere you needed to. check your .htaccess file in the directory where you installed wordpress. see if there is anything in there with the old url left over, ie. the url with port 8888. if it's wrong, replace it with the new one.

otherwise, try grep-ing through the directory for :8888 and see if that string exists anywhere its not supposed to.

use wingrep if you're on windows: http://www.wingrep.com/

Here's a tutorial on grep if you're not familiar: http://www.unixref.com/guides/grepGuide.html

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. All I had to do was to use another browser. The problem was cache.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I was running MAMP with ports 8888 and 8889 and installed Wordpress. When it asked for my port put in 8888.

What happened was it hardcoded the URL location to be localhost:8888/wordpress, so when I wanted to change the port to 80, it would redirect me there from localhost/wordpress

What I did was run MAMP with the original ports, 8888 and 8889, which allowed me to access the dashboard, from there I went to the "Settings" tab and change the "WordPress Address" and the "Site Address".

When I clicked "Save Changes" it brought up an error page, presumably because now it was being forwarded from localhost:8888/wordpress to localhost/wordpress, but when I switched the port back to 80 on MAMP and went to localhost/wordpress I was able to access everything again.

Comment: I've been handed a wordpress site by an MAMP user to upload to my Linux server.  Unfortunately, I don't have a  Mac so cannot run MAMP myself -- do you know if there's a direct database change that can fix this?

Comment: yes there is. Remove the :8888 part from siteurl and home properties in the wp_options table in the database then clear the browsing data of your browser and try. it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when i was trying to run a WordPress site using XAMPP which was originally created and run by a mac user using MAMP.

I fixed the issue by removing the :8888 part from siteurl and home properties in the wp_options table in the database and **clearing the browsing data** (Cookies and other site data / Cached images and files) of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the task manager as an administrator then go to "services" and stop W3SVC service, it will solve the problem!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).